# Bootstrap - Modals autoload for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Rails 3.2 and the twitter-bootsrap-rails gem [(link)](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails).

I have a modal, this is the html.erb:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3><%= t '.add_category_title' %></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= render :partial => 'wgform' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

this modal should be hidden when the page loads, and triggered with a button:

```
<a class="btn" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><%= t '.add_category_btn' %></a>
```

but for some reason, the modal appear when the page loads, with css attribute "display:block;" (it should be "display:none;"). 
The "X" on the top right works right to dismiss it, and the button correctly shows the modal (if clicked after closing it).

The strange thing is that all was working one hour ago, and I didn't modified that file.

I'm stuck, don't know where to look.

Comment: Any Javascript errors appearing in your browser console when the page loads?  Maybe something is going wrong on page load that's preventing the hiding code from running.

Comment: @Ryan no, no errors on the browser's console.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, you say you didn't change that file, so are there other files you've modified in the last hour?

Comment: well, some changes in the gemfile (i pulled from our repo, i was behind some commits) and other stuff regarding tests with rspec and capybara... then i've done a bundle update.

Comment: Solved. After the bundle update, i did a "rails g bootsrap:install" (as the official readme says). That command would overwrite my app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js.coffee in a bad way. 

That was the problem. I reverted the changes in that file, and now all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved editing bootstrap.js.coffee (see the comments above).

bootstrap.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
  $("body > .topbar").scrollSpy()
$ ->
  $(".tabs").tabs()
$ ->
  $("a[rel=twipsy]").twipsy live: true
$ ->
  $("a[rel=popover]").popover offset: 10
$ ->
  $(".topbar-wrapper").dropdown()
$ ->
  $(".alert-message").alert()
$ ->
  domModal = $(".modal").modal(
    backdrop: true
    closeOnEscape: true
  )
  $(".open-modal").click ->
    domModal.toggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: block;">
```

why do you have `style="display: block;"` there? remove it

Comment: mistake, copied from the running example on the bootstrap page